# Programmatically sorting a data.frame()

Tags: r

I'm using the following method to sort a data.frame.

```
# Dummy data
dat <- data.frame(a=letters[1:26],b=runif(26),c=rnorm(26))
# Sort
dat <- dat[with(dat, order(-b)),]
```

I'd like to be able to generate "-b" using something akin to paste so I can sort programmatically.

Something like:

```
dat <- dat[with(dat, order(paste("-b"))),]
```

I've tried things like `paste()`, `cat()`, `get()`, `getElement()`, to no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

how about this?

```
sort.var <- 'b'
inverse <- TRUE
dat <- dat[order(dat[[sort.var]],decreasing=inverse),]
```

Answer (score 3):

You're making this harder on yourself than you need to:

```
dat <- dat[order(dat[,"b"], decreasing=TRUE),]
```

Now you can specify the column as a character string.